# Updating multiple generic fields in a document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am storing notification information in a MongoDB collection. In my collection, I am distinguishing between multiple event types and event instances. In order to reduce database load when the frontend queries for data, this information is aggregated into one document (that spills over into additional documents once too many events are registered).

All events carry an attribute `status` which is used to tell, whether or not the event has been read/seen by the user. The user has the option to mark all elements of either one event type or all event types as read.

I can easily create the update query to mark all events of a certain type as read:

```
{"$set": {"notifications.IMPORT_SUCCEEDED.events.$[].status": "r"}}
```

However, I want to avoid having to iterate over all event types in order to mark all events of all types as read, since this list may get quite long (dozens of event types) - is there any possibility to update all (sub) keys within a document (basically exchanging the event type `IMPORT_SUCCEEDED` with a wildcard)? Basically, I would like to do something like this:

```
{"$set": {"notifications.${}.events.$[].status": "r"}}
```

**Example document:**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bd1752877ada457400c182f"), 
    "count" : 1337.0, 
    "status" : "u", 
    "notifications" : {
        "IMPORT_FAILED" : {
            "count" : 1000.0, 
            "status" : "u", 
            "events" : [
                {
                    "text" : "bla", 
                    "status" : "u"
                }, 
                {
                    "text" : "bla", 
                    "status" : "u"
                }, 
                {
                    "text" : "bla", 
                    "status" : "u"
                }, 
                {
                    "text" : "bla", 
                    "status" : "u"
                }, 
                {
                    "text" : "bla", 
                    "status" : "u"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        "IMPORT_SUCCEEDED" : {
            "count" : 337.0, 
            "status" : "u", 
            "events" : [
                {
                    "text" : "bla", 
                    "status" : "r"
                }, 
                {
                    "text" : "bla", 
                    "status" : "r"
                }, 
                {
                    "text" : "bla", 
                    "status" : "r"
                }, 
                {
                    "text" : "bla", 
                    "status" : "r"
                }, 
                {
                    "text" : "bla", 
                    "status" : "r"
                }
            ]
        }
    }, 
    "reference_id" : 42.0
}
```

Comment: It is not possible to use all in embedded documents. Would you be able to store them as embedded arrays ? Something like `notifications:[{k:"IMPORT_FAILED", v:{..}}, {k:...,v:..}...]`. You can then use `{"notifications.$[].events.$[].status": "r"}}`

Comment: @Veeram thanks for the reply - I was afraid that would be the case. I thought about using arrays but that would make all other queries way more complicated (managing the aggregation in the python backend). But if you formulate your comment as an answer, I will be glad to mark it as the accepted answer for anyone who has the same issue in the future.